# Synonym of 'lexical' in spelling similarity

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Word [lexicial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lexical) is a magic word for me to remember.

In MW dictionary,

> of or relating to words or the vocabulary of a language as distinguished from its grammar and construction Our language has many lexical borrowings from other languages.

Although I relate it to word 'letter', it takes seconds to recall its meaning from my memory when read it.

Is there a better word than 'letter'.

Answer (score -1):

You could envision all letters at once, if you were to use the word 'Alphabet' when referring to letters, or use the letter in its own name, when referring back to one in particular.

Comment: You voluntarily voted me down without sharing the enlightening groundwork that supported your observations. That's fierce.

Comment: No, it's not me. leave me your email, I send a screenshot to you.

Comment: I forget to accept. After send you email, I accept and upvote, thank you.